# can I delete the content of the array im loping after calling saveInBackgroundWithBLock in Parse

Tags: ios, loops, parse-platform, objective-c-blocks

I have an application that saves public urls and then uploads them syns a reference to them in parse when the a button is clicked. After I make the calls to parse, in the block, I want to reset the array that I'm using, but I'm a little unclear if removing the reference will create some sort of null pointer error. Here is my code

```
 for (NSString *theString in sharedDataController.filesToUpload) {
             // Create PFObject with recipe information
             PFObject *parseImage = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Photos"];
             [parseImage setObject:theString forKey:@"myURL"];
             [parseImage setObject:object forKey:@"photoUser"];    
             [parseImage saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
                 if (!error) {
                     // Show success message
                     NSLog(@"Parse Image Saved");
                 } else {
                     NSLog(@"Parse Image Error");
                 }

             }];
         // if I delete the contents sharedDAtaController.filesToUpload here, will that create an issue 
         }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating objects from array and uploading all objects one by one. But **Parse** also provide you a bulk upload in array. So create array of **PFObjects** and upload it to **Parse**

```
 NSMutableArray *arrParseObjects = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
 for (NSString *theString in sharedDataController.filesToUpload) {
             // Create PFObject with recipe information
             PFObject *parseImage = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Photos"];
             [parseImage setObject:theString forKey:@"myURL"];
             [parseImage setObject:object forKey:@"photoUser"];    
             [arrParseObjects addObject:parseImage];
         // if I delete the contents sharedDAtaController.filesToUpload here, will that create an issue 
         }

   [PFObject saveAllInBackground:arrParseObjects block:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *PF_NULLABLE_S error){
        if (succeeded) {
            // You just saved all objects in Parse
        }else{

        }
    }];
```

End if we talk about your crash on removing object. We never can remove any object from the array while we are looping through it. 1 solution to it is that we need to use **reverse enumeration** to it.

```
[sharedDAtaController.filesToUpload enumerateObjectsWithOptions:NSEnumerationReverse usingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        // Remove the object after work
        // Make sure your array is a NSMutableArray.
    }];
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will create a problem. The calls to `saveInBackgroundWithBlock` are not finished outside of the completion block. You will need some method to coalesce all the calls and only delete `sharedDAtaController.filesToUpload` once the last completion block fires.

You could make an **atomic** property "pendingSaves", increment it each time before you call `saveInBackgroundWithBlock`, decrement it in the completion block, and delete `sharedDAtaController.filesToUpload` in the completion block of  `saveInBackgroundWithBlock` only if `pendingSaves == 0`